# Convergence of a Series using the p-series Approach

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, self-learning

Determine if $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ converges using the $p$-series approach.

**Answer**: Is this a simple as saying that
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \cos\left(\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

and since $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is a convergent $p$-series, then its sum is finite, and the cosine of a finite number is itself a finite number, hence the given series is convergent?

Comment: $\sum\cos(1/n^2)\ne\cos\sum1/n^2$(!!!!!)

Comment: What is the limit of the general term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \cos\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \cos(0) = 1 \neq 0$, then the given series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ diverges.